# HTML not accessing CSS external file

Tags: html, css

Beginning stage of learning CSS.
Working on a project that is having me modify HTML file externally, internally, and inline. Have successfully accomplished all but external.

HTML file

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Methods for Adding CSS</title>
      <link rel=”stylesheet” href="styled.css">
      <style>
        p {color: white; background-color: green;font-size:18px}
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div>Style me via the external method!</div>
      <p>I would like to be styled with the internal method, please.</p>
      <button style=background-color:orange;font-size:18px;>Inline Method</button>
    </body>
```

CSS file

```css
    div {
      background-color: red;
      color: white;
      font-size: 32px;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
```

Line 8 is the piece of code that links to the external file.
The HTML and CSS files reside within the same folder.

I have tried creating new CSS files within the folder, from VSCode and by ctrl+ clicking the reference link within the terminal and dragging/dropping from folder to VSCode.
Also tried `./styled.css` and `../styled.css`, opened the css file from the folder to verify the code in there.
Opened in chrome dev tools, network, selected CSS. It does not display any files.
Reasonably confident the syntax is correct.
I feel like the HTML is not locating the CSS file but at a loss of how to remedy this.

Comment: How does your file directory look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the wrong quote in line number 8 `”stylesheet”`. Change the quote characters to `"stylesheet"` and it will work.

Comment: I replaced the quotations and it works.  I don't understand this at all.  Thank you.

Comment: Those fancy quotation marks are not interpreted properly in HTML. They're not the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Please change double-quotes from ” to " and clear browser's history. I hope it will work fine.

Comment: To clarify, you have styled quote characters in your markup as though pasted from a word processor. They're not valid HTML.

Comment: I copied out of google docs so i understand the error as explained.
I am curious how you were able to tell?

Answer (score 0):

If everything is correct, the filename and dir. Try clearing the cache of your browser.

Comment: no dice, but good reminder